# how to pass javascript array to oracle store procedure by ado parameter object

Tags: arrays, oracle, asp-classic, ado, jscript

I am working on a asp+oracle web project, and I need a multiple user select function.

1, use javascript build up a string array :

```
 var userArray = ["Simon","Sheng","Cheng"];
```

2, pass it by ado parameter object,but I don't know how to fill Parameter ojbect :

```
var cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
var param = cmd.CreateParameter("par",????????????)<--I don't know how to fill;
```

3, create store procedure in oracle

```
    create or replace package demo_pkg
    as
       type charArray is table of varchar2(255) index by binary_integer;
       type t_cursor is ref cursor;
    procedure p_test(p_id in charArray,p_cursor out t_cursor );
    end;

    create or replace package body demo_pkg
    as
    procedure p_test (p_id in charArray,p_cursor out t_cursor )
    AS
v_cursor t_cursor;
    BEGIN
open v_cursor for
      select last_name from employees where last_name in (select * from table(cast(p_id as charArray)))
p_cursor := s_test;
    end;
    end;
```

After 3 days google, I still here, so who can help me?

Comment: Please focus your question what is causing you problems here ? Is it using ADO to pass a value to a Oracle stored procedure, if so simplify your example an remove the parts you don't have a problem with (unless its all three of course) then maybe you should split it into multiple questions

Comment: yes,maby I ask oracle store procedure first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is:

```js
CreateParameter( name, type, direction, size, value )
```

The values you'll need are:

```
adVarChar = 200
AdArray = 0x2000
adParamInput = 1
```

And you'll call it like:

```js
var param = cmd.CreateParameter( 'par', adVarChar + AdArray, adParamInput, 255, userArray )
```

Comment: I’d guess that he is using classic ASP with JScript as server-side language. That means he can use all the ASP objects, including `Server`.

Comment: first, yes,I am using classic ASP with JScript as server-side language.