# An Oracle stored procedure accept array(table) parameter in package example needed

Tags: arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, open-array-parameters

This question is a part of my question [how to pass javascript array to oracle store procedure by ado parameter object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419308/how-to-pass-javascript-array-to-oracle-store-procedure-by-ado-parameter-object)

I think divide it to 3 small parts will get answer faster.

For this question.

I know we can declare a table type and use

```
select last_name 
from employees in (select * from table(cast(my_table_type_var as my_table_type));
```

but I always get error from create new package which include a procedure has this. and I read some thread said I need to declear a sql(in schema) type because sql and pl/slq are not using same engine. I try create type in schema by spl*plus, but still get same errors
so I need a working package example for this first please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a SQL object to call the `TABLE` operator from a `SELECT`. Here's a small example (9iR2):

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE table_number is TABLE OF NUMBER;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(table_number(1,2,3));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2
           3
```

You can use a function here instead (note that my TYPE is still defined outside the package):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg AS
  2     FUNCTION f RETURN table_number;
  3  END;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg AS
  2     FUNCTION f RETURN table_number IS
  3     BEGIN
  4        RETURN table_number(4,5,6);
  5     END;
  6  END;
  7  /

Package body created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM table(pkg.f);

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           4
           5
           6
```

Comment: Thank you very much, after your example I read [table function description](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php), I understand most of this. but I am debugging my own package store procedur, there is no error for creating it, but I got error for calling it. I am new, I don't know how to formate my code in comment. I add all my coed by the next comment. hope you can help me.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_table IS TABLE of VARCHAR2(255);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE simon_pkg 
IS 
TYPE t_table IS TABLE of VARCHAR2(255); 
TYPE c_cursor IS ref CURSOR;
PROCEDURE f (t_input in t_table,c_out out c_cursor);
END; 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY simon_pkg 
IS
PROCEDURE f (t_input in t_table,c_out out c_cursor) 
IS 
v_cursor c_cursor; 
BEGIN 
OPEN v_cursor FOR 
SELECT last_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE last_name IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(t_input));
c_out := v_cursor;
END f; 
END; 
/

Comment: I will create a new question.I can formate my code in comment.